# Is there a chance to vectorize the "if-else" condition using omp simd function vectorization?

Tags: fortran, vectorization, gfortran

I am working with these codes (as I post below 2 codes: the original and with omp simd function vectorization).

This is the original code, that I want to vectorize:

```
PROGRAM TEST
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL(KIND=8), DIMENSION(2000):: A,B,C
  REAL(KIND=8)::TIME1,TIME2  
  INTEGER::I,K

     !Initial condition    
     !$OMP SIMD           !This part of course could be vectorized
      DO I=1, 2000        !even without !$OMP SIMD statement  
         A(I)=2.0+I/100   
         B(I)=1.0+I/200
         C(I)=0.2+I/500          
      END DO      
     !$OMP END SIMD

    CALL CPU_TIME(TIME1)

    DO K=1, 1000000
       !$OMP SIMD              !This part which I want to vectorize 
        DO I=1, 2000           !but of course it was not, since
           IF(A(I)>0.0) THEN   !if-else statement exists
              C(I)=A(I)+B(I)                          
           ELSE
              C(I)=2.0*I           
           END IF          
        END DO
       !$OMP END SIMD         
    END DO     

    CALL CPU_TIME(TIME2)

    PRINT *, 'C(2000)           = ', C(2000) 
    PRINT *, 'Elapsed real time = ', TIME2-TIME1, 'second(s)'
END PROGRAM TEST
```

I know when the "if-else" statement exists, the compiler couldn't do the auto-vectorization, and in my case it also didn't work even I've put !$OMP DO SIMD, which is clear. And also to my knowledge only the intrinsic function could be vectorized automatically by the compiler.

A few days ago, I just read a presentation which there is a chance to vectorize a function using "OMP SIMD FUNCTION VECTORIZATION". So I try changing the original code as below:

```
PROGRAM TEST
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL(KIND=8), DIMENSION(2000):: A,B,C
  REAL(KIND=8)::TIME1,TIME2
  REAL(KIND=8), EXTERNAL::VEC  
  INTEGER::I,K

     !Initial condition    
     !$OMP SIMD       
      DO I=1, 2000
         A(I)=2.0+I/100   
         B(I)=1.0+I/200
         C(I)=0.2+I/500          
      END DO      
     !$OMP END SIMD

    CALL CPU_TIME(TIME1)

    DO K=1, 1000000
       !$OMP SIMD  
        DO I=1, 2000 
           C(I)=VEC(A(I),B(I),I)           
        END DO
       !$OMP END SIMD        
    END DO     

    CALL CPU_TIME(TIME2)

    PRINT *, 'C(2000)           = ', C(2000) 
    PRINT *, 'Elapsed real time = ', TIME2-TIME1, 'second(s)'
END PROGRAM TEST

FUNCTION VEC(IN1,IN2,IN3) RESULT(OUT1)
 IMPLICIT NONE
 REAL(KIND=8)::IN1,IN2,OUT1
 INTEGER::IN3 

          !IN1 = A(I)
          !IN2 = B(I)
          !IN3 = I  

     !$OMP DECLARE SIMD(VEC)    
           IF(IN1>0.0) THEN
              OUT1=IN1+IN2                            
           ELSE
              OUT1=2.0*IN3         
           END IF          
END FUNCTION VEC
```

but the vectorization still didn't work. Do you have any idea, how could I vectorize with this !$OMP SIMD? Or it also couldn't be vectorized (*it's just a same case with the failure of auto vectorization by the compiler when non-intrinsic function exists*)? Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Omp do simd inside  a parallel region would request  both threads and simd vectorization.  I suppose the way you put it a compiler would be justified in ignoring it or throwing a warning.
Omp simd doesn't require a parallel region, in case you intended that.
Vectorization of a conditional is more likely to work with merge syntax.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't get what you mean. What is your answer of my question? Is "Vectorization of a conditional is more likely to work with merge syntax." your answer? If so, what kind of "merge syntax" you mean? Thanks.

PS: Yes I do know that in this case I only need to write $OMP SIMD instead of $OMP DO SIMD. I've revised it.

Comment: The first version you posted on the Intel site vectorizes with no problem, so I don't know why you think you didn't correct your errors.

Comment: C(I) = merge(A(I)+B(I),2.0*I,A(I)>0.0) should vectorize even with gfortran -O3 -ffast-math

Comment: I don't know why, but in my case it didn't work with `MERGE` syntax using gfortran. I have tried using flag `-O3 -ffast-math` and `-Ofast`, but both of them didn't work. FYI, for gfortran, I was using gfortran 5.4.0.